# How to remove to expiry time in php using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
How to remove the expiry time in php using mysql database....
```

I want to remove the expiry time which are derived from mysql db..In my code i want to compare the show time from database with current time,to get the showtime which is greater than the current time.(Eg), showtime="10:30 AM,2:30 PM,6:30 PM,9:30 PM" and curent time is 03:21 PM.

```
Getting output:   
{"offer_details":[{"showtime":["10:30 AM","2:30 PM","6:30 PM","9:30 PM"]}],"success":1,"message":"Successfully found "}

Expected output:   
{"offer_details":[{"showtime":["6:30 PM","9:30 PM"]}],"success":1,"message":"Successfully found "}



    $result=mysql_query("select * from offer_details where movieid='$movieid' and date_value='$date_value' and offer_status!='Expired'")or die (mysql_error());

    $offer_details=array();

$offer_details['showtime']=explode(',',$row['showtime']); 

 $av = sizeof($offer_details['showtime']);

          echo $showtime[i];
Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare time via hour like this:

```
foreach($offer_details['showtime'] as $key=>$showTime){
    if(date("H", strtotime($showTime)) < date("H", strtotime("now"))){
        unset($offer_details['showtime'][$key]);
    }
}
array_values($offer_details['showtime']);
```

Comment: am getting the output is like this. {"offer_details":[{"showtime":{"2":"6:30 PM","3":"9:30 PM"}}],"success":1,"message":"Successfully found "}

Comment: My expected output: {"offer_details":[{"showtime":{"6:30 PM","9:30 PM"}}],"success":1,"message":"Successfully found "} I dont know how to remove the key value

Comment: you can try `array_values($offer_details['showtime']);`.

Answer (score 0):

When you explode the showtime string you actually obtain strings which are formatted as times but remain as strings. That is why you cannot get the result when you compare with the current time as strings ("8:00 AM" will always be greater than "3:00 PM"). I suggest you store the showtimes as different fields in your database (with datetime types) so that you only pick those greater than now. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example and see if this helps.

```
<?php
$offer_details['showtime']= ["10:30 AM","2:30 PM","6:30 PM","9:30 PM"];

//$now = strtotime('now');
$now = strtotime('3:30 PM');
$showtimes = array();

foreach($offer_details['showtime'] as $showtime) {
    if(strtotime($showtime) >= $now) {
        $showtimes[] = $showtime;
    }
}

print_r($showtimes); //outputs Array ( [0] => 6:30 PM [1] => 9:30 PM )
```